# Changing singular icon color when hovering link

Tags: css, hover, icons, font-awesome, mousehover

First question at StackOverflow.

I've been busting my head to figure this one out.
My main menu options (@ [gabrielpinto.pt](http://gabrielpinto.pt)) are made of text and icon (FontAwesome).

I want to change the hover color of the icon WHEN I'm hovering the written link.

Here's one of the menu option's markup:

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation col-md-8" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-menu-principal-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="menu nav-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-24" class="fa-street-view menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-24">
        <a href="http://gabrielpinto.pt/">Gabriel Pinto</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm just a beginner in HTML and CSS, and I've tried a lot of different rules but without any positive result.

Example:

```
a.fa-street-view:hover li::before {
color: #bc4676; }
```

What CSS rule will make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
.fa-street-view:hover {
    color: #bc4676;
}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gtr45hk7/

**Edit**

I added the `.fa` class to `.fa-street-view` in your html to make the example work.

**Edit 2**

I just looked at your site. Try this:

```
.main-navigation li:hover::before {
  color: #bc4676;
}
```

If you want to match the link transitions, this might do the trick:

```
.main-navigation li::before {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jack,

I applied your suggestion without adding the .fa class and it didn't work.

That's the thing, I would have to add stuff into the theme's html, which I want to avoid at all costs because of future theme updates.

I can always try and ask the theme's author to add it in the next update.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You could try being more specific with the selector, like: `li.fa-street-view:hover`

Comment: @GSPinto See my revision

Comment: Hi Jack, 

It works fine on IE 11 and Firefox but not on Chrome (webkit) ??
Using Chrome will only change the color of the icon, not the text.

Comment: Ok, nevermind the above.
Had to restart windows because I left this PC on suspend mode while I made the changes on the laptop.
I guess Chrome needed a hard reset.

Thank you Jack!

Comment: @GSPinto Did that take care of your issue? Consider marking as answer :)

Comment: Done mate!

Sorry, newbie in Stack!
Thanks again!